# How can I apply a fixed price to bundle products?

Tags: shopify, discount

For a shopify store, I am trying to create a build-a-box bundle with a fixed price. Let say user can select any 3 products from a collection for $100.

My planning is like this:

1. Create an alternative page for user to select products
2. When user has selected products, add to cart will add them with a discount at once

However, I cannot set a fixed amount or percentage discount since the price is fixed at $100. I don't know what user selects when I create a discount.

What is the correct approach? I plan to use this approach because the inventory will be correctly deducted

p.s. I am looking for technical approach but not using 3rd party apps

Comment: Without APP i don't think so you can achieve this functionally because prices can never be handles through front-end customization in Shopify.

Comment: I mean I am building my solution so I don't want to use other 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 1):

The correct technical approach, assuming you do not want to use Plus, is to use an App Proxy when the items are in the cart and you want the customer to checkout. At that point you can ask your custom App to deal with the discounting you want.

Not sure you can avoid using some API calls in this case.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what and how I can apply the discount. There are BXGY, fixed amount (- $$) and percentage discount. When the customer selects some random products with different prices, how can I apply a suitable discount on the fly?

Can app proxy help with that?

Comment: Welcome to the part of Shopify not really A-grade. Even with Apps, Shopify bundling and discounting, tiered pricing, quantity breaks etc are all a hodge-podge dogs breakfast of murky soup. You have total control your way, but you need to think real deep to avoid all those pitfalls.